# Emit value on a search button depending on checkbox state, AngualrJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, redux, rxjs

My app has a **Search Button**, that hits an **internal API with a GET Request**. Then we fetch Data that are **protected** in some cases. I have a **checkbox** which is set to **true** by default to simulate the Back-End behavior.

If that box is unchecked then we **add a parameter to our query GET Request** `protection: false.` This tells the Back-End to give us access to unprotected Data.

My question is this. **How to keep watch of the checkbox state in Angular Controller, and this change gets emitted to the search button?**

I understand that I need to use `$scope.watch` for that, but AngularJS isn't my strong suit, so please help.

The protection parameter is passed as an **Action from Redux**, down to an **RxJS Epic**, to the **Reducer** and then injected to `endpoint.js` and `service.js` files that handle thoe requests.

*That is done and working. My big problem is how to handle the angular part.* **Below you will find the code for the HTML and Controller files.**

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="getData(something, protection)"
     ng-disabled="Ctrl.loading">
     Run Search
</button>
<span>Protection
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Ctrl.Protection">
</span>
```

**Controller.js**

```
  $scope.getData = (something, protection) => {
    ctrl.getSomecData(protection, protection);
    ctrl.saveRecentSearch(something);
  };
```

**So, one final go. I want to be able to check and uncheck the box, and that change should be emitted to the search button, and then inject that parameter in the GET Request.**

Please help me do that in Angularjs. I haven't worked with it before this job, and it is really frustrating. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use ngChange directive of angular js on checkbox element.
method binded with ng-change attribute will called whenever checkbox is checked or unchecked.
further $watch is not recommended since it hits performance of the page.

Html:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="Ctrl.Protection" ng-change="change()">
```

In your controller :

```
$scope.change = function() {
    if(this.Protection){
      //whatever you wish to do here
      $scope.getData($scope.something, this.protection);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Hhhmmm, and I don't need anything for the button??? Weird... My thinking was all wrong. Will try it out. Thanks for the response..

Comment: Partially. For the Angular Part this was part of the solution. I needed to actually, create another action in Redux, and pass that as an argument, `on-click`. Thanks for the answer.